# Remove 'Edit this page to modify your web part content' from CEWP

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I added Content Editor Webpart in my Sharepoint page. If there is no content provided in CEWP then 'Edit this page to modify your web part content' default text is displaying in the page. How do i remove this default text.

Note: I added this CEWP in page layout, using this page layout I have created several pages. So now I have to modify in page layout.

Comment: How about alternatively modifying the CEWP content into the page layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I follow what you want here, but can't you just add a blank space as default for your CEWP?

```
<Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Web Part from its drop down (right hand corner of web part) and under `Advanced` un-tick `Allow edit from personal view`. It removes this wording.